# <Object> is not a member of <struct>

Tags: c++, opencv, struct, namespaces

I have a question about C++. I'm working with OpenCV. I'm pretty new to both.

I have this declaration:

```
struct scoredRotatedRect
{
    double score;
    RotatedRect ellipse;
    vector<Point> contour;

};
```

The problem is that when I declare a `scoredRotatedRect`, it recognizes the `double` as a member but not the non-primitive types as members.

I.e.,

```
cur_scoredRotatedRect.score=0; // not a problem
cur_scoredRotatedRect.ellipse=a_RotatedRect; // get an error
```

The error is

> "'ellipse' : is not a member of 'scoredRotatedRect'".

What is causing this?

Comment: -1:  Please provide a SSCCE.  Also, if the answer you propose fixed the problem, then `'ellipse' : is not a member of 'scoredRotatedRec` would not have been the *first* compiler error.  The first (main) problem would have been that `vector` was unknown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that I was doing this:

```
struct scoredRotatedRect
{
    double score;
    RotatedRect ellipse;
    vector<Point> contour;

};

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
```

as opposed to this:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

struct scoredRotatedRect
{
    double score;
    RotatedRect ellipse;
    vector<Point> contour;

};
```

so I guess the initial struct declaration didn't know what RotatedRect was referring to and just ignored it (?)

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. If no declaration for `RotatedRect` is visible, the compiler should complain when it sees `RotatedRect ellipse;`, not just later when it sees a reference to it.

Comment: That's odd. That change fixed it? Because if it didn't understand what a `RotatedRect` was, the compiler should have given you an error saying as much on the line `RotateRect ellipse;`... like "unrecognized symbol" or somesuch.

Comment: Better is to just take both `using`s out and explicitly qualify them.

Comment: -1:  `using namespace std` is not the best (or only) way to fix this problem.

Comment: Yes, this fixes the problem, no I do not know why. John - I'd appreciate you not downvoting my question/answer as 1) The question is valid and so is the answer 2) the answer is not intended to be a final answer (hence why I didn't accept it), so of course it's not "the best" way to solve it. I was hoping that someone could offer an explanation for why this change allows compilation, and more importantly, why I'm getting these funky errors.